# Android: How to display the route between two GeoPoint?

Tags: android, android-mapview, geopoints

Using the example of the next page and it works perfect.
http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html

But when I change the coordinates to my country (Chile), I can not make it show the route.

I think it must be a problem with this.

```
UrlString StringBuilder = new StringBuilder ();
urlString.append ("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
urlString.append ("& saddr =");/ / from
urlString.append (Double.ToString ((double) src.getLatitudeE6 () / 1.0E6));
urlString.append (",");
urlString.append (Double.ToString ((double) src.getLongitudeE6 () / 1.0E6));
urlString.append ("& daddr =");/ / to
urlString.append (Double.ToString ((double) dest.getLatitudeE6 () / 1.0E6));
urlString.append (",");
urlString.append (Double.ToString ((double) dest.getLongitudeE6 () / 1.0E6));
urlString.append ("& ie = UTF8 & 0 & om = 0 & output = kml");
```

Is that the problem?

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried the generated URL in the browser? What are the coordinates that don't work?

Comment: logcat error what you get also paste it..and give more explnation..

Answer (score 0):

LOGCat: 
12-30 01:53:29.688: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 699 objects / 57992 bytes in 61ms
12-30 01:53:52.207: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4288 objects / 251664 bytes in 64ms
12-30 01:53:52.437: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 10135 objects / 618320 bytes in 63ms
12-30 01:53:52.648: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4973 objects / 325032 bytes in 60ms
12-30 01:53:52.869: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6369 objects / 389008 bytes in 67ms
12-30 01:53:53.127: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8604 objects / 656224 bytes in 67ms
12-30 01:53:53.347: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8603 objects / 609784 bytes in 67ms
12-30 01:53:53.477: I/Maps.MyLocationOverlay(444): Request updates from gps
12-30 01:53:53.747: I/MapActivity(444): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
12-30 01:53:53.747: E/MapActivity(444): Couldn't get connection factory client
12-30 01:53:54.037: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1000 objects / 366296 bytes in 71ms
12-30 01:53:55.858: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8102 objects / 505920 bytes in 247ms
12-30 01:53:56.218: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 135 objects / 22680 bytes in 57ms
12-30 01:53:58.199: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXPLICIT freed 137 objects / 23768 bytes in 61ms
12-30 01:54:00.468: D/dalvikvm(444): GC_EXPLICIT freed 162 objects / 46864 bytes in 56ms

the URL in the browser works fine.

from: -36.738486,-73.0893 to: -36.825623,-73.054372

Thanks!